# Deleting Invalid Duplicate Rows in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table which stores the check-in times of employees through Time Machine on the basis of a username. If an employee punches multiple times then there would be multiple records of his check-ins which would only have a time difference of few seconds in between. Obviously only the first record is valid. All the other entries are invalid and must be deleted from the Table. How can i do it if i can select all the checkin records of an employee for the current date?

The Data in the db is as follows.

```
Username               Checktime                       CheckType
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:44 AM                Check-In
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:46 AM                Check-In
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:50 AM                Check-In 
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:53 AM                Check-In
```

Comment: Do you want to delete all Check-Ins in the same date, or just the ones that follow another Check-In of the same User, and not a Check-out of that user?

Comment: currently i want to delete all the checkins which are in span of 15seconds from first checkin. Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ;WITH users_CTE as (
 select rank() over (partition by Username order by Checktime) as rnk from users
 )

 DELETE FROM users_CTE where rnk <> 1
```

--For your second requirement try this query

```
 ;WITH users_CTE as (
 select *,rank() over (partition by Username order by Checktime) as rnk from users
 )
,CTE2 as (select Username,MIN(CheckTime) as minTime,DATEADD(mi,1,MIN(CheckTime)) as maxTime from users_CTE 
 group by Username)



delete from users where Checktime in(
select c1.Checktime from users_CTE c1 left join CTE2 c2
on c1.Checktime > c2.minTime and c1.Checktime <= c2.maxTime
where c2.Username is not null and c1.Username in(

select c1.Username from users_CTE c1 left join CTE2 c2
on c1.Checktime > c2.minTime and c1.Checktime <= c2.maxTime
group by c1.Username,c2.Username 
having COUNT(*) > 1))
```

--For your changed requirements pls check this query below

```
alter table users add flag varchar(2)

;WITH users_CTE as (
 select *,rank() over (partition by Username order by Checktime) as rnk from users
 )
,CTE2 as (select Username,MIN(CheckTime) as minTime,DATEADD(mi,1,MIN(CheckTime)) as maxTime from users_CTE 
 group by Username)


update u SET u.flag = 'd' from users_CTE u inner join (
select c1.Checktime from users_CTE c1 left join CTE2 c2
on c1.Checktime > c2.minTime and c1.Checktime <= c2.maxTime
where c2.Username is not null and c1.Username in(

select c1.Username from users_CTE c1 left join CTE2 c2
on c1.Checktime > c2.minTime and c1.Checktime <= c2.maxTime
group by c1.Username,c2.Username 
having COUNT(*) > 1)) a
on u.Checktime=a.Checktime
```

--Check the latest query with DeletFlag

```
;WITH users_CTE as 
(
 select *,row_number() over (partition by Username order by Checktime) as row from users
)
,CTE as(
select row,Username,Checktime,CheckType,0 as totalSeconds,'N' as Delflag from users_CTE where row=1 
union all
select t.row,t.Username,t.Checktime,t.CheckType,CASE WHEN (c.totalSeconds + DATEDIFF(SECOND,c.Checktime,t.Checktime))  >= 60 then 0 else (c.totalSeconds + DATEDIFF(SECOND,c.Checktime,t.Checktime)) end as totalSeconds,
CASE WHEN (c.totalSeconds + DATEDIFF(SECOND,c.Checktime,t.Checktime))  >= 60 then 'N' else 'Y' end as Delflag
--CASE WHEN c.totalSeconds <= 60  then 'Y' else 'N' end as Delflag
from users_CTE t inner join CTE c
on t.row=c.row+1
)

select Username,Checktime,CheckType,Delflag from CTE
```

Comment: just a little bit more this deletes all the records from current date except the first one.What if i want to delete records only that occur within a minute of first record?

Comment: Hey did you get what you wanted from the second query?

Comment: Not Yet i haven't tested it yet i was discussing it with my supervisor and now requirements are bit changed..darn!

Comment: oh ok but you can check the query above and let me know.Thanks

Comment: Now instead of deleting the records(invalid) i have to set their flag as 'duplicate' which come within a minute of original record. Afterwards i will delete all the records which have a flag set as 'Duplicate'

Comment: ok thats simple you can use the same query above and instead of delete update the flag

Comment: Your second query is working perfectly fine only hitch is that it selects MIN(CHECKTIME) and deletes all the invalid records. However, records which occur after 1 minute of first record are valid records and can themselves have duplicate records. so now i have to check duplicate records for every record of an employee for current date and delete them iam posting some dummy data for your understanding..BTW u rock man :)

Comment: Username               Checktime                       CheckType
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:44 AM                Check-In
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:46 AM                Check-In
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:50 AM                Check-In 
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:17:50 AM                Check-In
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:17:55 AM                Check-In

so now 1st record is valid and your query is deleting 2nd and 3rd record which is correct and now afterwards i need to check 4th record and 5th record will be invalid for 4th record and will be deleted

Comment: what would be your output here?

Comment: The output will be

Username               Checktime                       CheckType
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:44 AM                Check-In
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:17:50 AM                Check-In

Comment: yes i got the problem.Let me try to get you the right solution here

Comment: hey chek the latest query.Here I have deleteFlag at the end.Just use that to update your table staright away.Now thi will handle repeating duplicates between 1 minute time intervals. if flag='N' then keep it and for flag='Y' delete these records

Comment: hey the query is working but its giving mis-results because you are comparing min part of date. What i actually wanted is that first record will always have delflag of N and all the records which come inside 1 min of it will have delflag of Y. Subsequently the record which will come after 1 min of first record will have delflag again set to N. Now any record which come under 1 min of second N delflag record will have delflag set to Y and so on. Posting some data for ur better understanding :)

Comment: Username               Checktime            CheckType    Delflag
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:44 AM     Check-In        N
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:50 AM     Check-In        Y
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:53 AM     Check-In        Y
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:16:50 AM     Check-In        Y
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:17:30 AM     Check-In        Y
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:17:55 AM     Check-In        N
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:17:59 AM     Check-In        Y
 HRA001            7/29/2012 8:18:57 AM     Check-In        N

Comment: Check the latest updated query.I hope this time its working as expected.Pls let me knw.

Comment: initial tests conclude that the query is working according to the requirements :) BRAVO!!

Comment: yeahhh i posted it coz i felt that it was not clear enough, even with you my requirements were changing. I marked your answer on that thread as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you verify the check-ins before inserting them into db. If there exists any check-in for this user, between this date and that date then do nothing else insert it

Comment: the insertion occurs from a time machine and i dont have its control. i can only filter out from the records inserted into db :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to order all records by time, subtract the latest time from the previous time per employee and, if the result is less than a certain threshold, delete the row(s) with the most recent time.

Comment: i want to subtract the time of all the records from first record only and if it will be lesser than timeout say 15 seconds delete the record

Answer (score 0):

You could try and RANK the records by checkin time and then delete all the records for each employee for each day which have RANK greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: Delete from employee where employee.checkin in (select checkin from employee where count(checkin)>1);

Answer (score 0):

http://codesimplified.com/2010/10/18/remove-duplicate-records-from-the-database-table/

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM timesheet 
WHERE timesheetRecordId <>(
                SELECT TOP 1 timesheetRecordId from timesheet  
                WHERE checkInDate=todaysDate AND employeeId=empId ORDER BY checkInTime ASC
               ) 
AND checkInDate=today's date AND empolyeeId=empId;
```

Comment: Thanx man i have got a feeling that this will actually work :)

Comment: A little more help here please. I am not able to compare the record's date 7/29/2012 8:16:44 AM in select subquery instead of today's date

Comment: You can do this: `WHERE checkIndate ='07/29/2012 08:16:44'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify a Target Table, from a Delete statement, in a Subquery of that same statement. So you can't do it with one single Delete statement.

What you can do is write a stored procedure. In your Stored Procedure you should create a Temporary Table containing the PKs returned by this Query:

```
select cht.pkey 
  from CheckTimeTable as cht
  where exists ( select pkey
                   from CheckTimeTable 
                   where username = cht.userName
                     and checkType = 'check-IN'
                     and Checktime >= subtime(cht.Checktime, '0 0:0:15.000000') 
                     and Checktime < cht.Checktime);
```

Then write another statement to delete those PKs from your original table, CheckTimeTable.

Note that the query above is for MySQL, so you'll need to find the way to subtract 15 seconds from a timestamp for your DBMS. In MySQL it's done like this:

```
subtime(cht.Checktime, '0 0:0:15.000000')
```

This query will return whichever CheckTime record that has another CheckTime record from the same user, with the type Check-In, and within 15 seconds earlier than its own checktime.

Comment: This query returns me every row because my data is only separated from few seconds of check-in times. What i basically want is every record which comes within 1 minute of my first record should be deleted. A record which comes after more than one min of first record shouldnt be deleted and then every record which comes within one minute of this second non-deleted record should be deleted and so on

Comment: and ultimately i want to do all this thing in a stored procedure so kindly give it your one more go :)

Comment: This query will only return every row if they are all with 15 seconds from each other, all Check-ins, and all of the same username. Is that the case?