# Select duplicate records created within a few minutes of the first

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My company has been receiving duplicate records in a database that are created up to 4 minutes after the first. Logically speaking, a group of records consists of the original record plus any subsequent records that were created within that 4 minute time frame. The initial record gets a `TO_DELETE` value of `'N'`, while each duplicate record gets a `TO_DELETE` value of `'Y'`. Each new group starts over with an `'N'` value.

With the help of [Deleting Invalid Duplicate Rows in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839893/deleting-invalid-duplicate-rows-in-sql), I've put together a query to select them but it's been running for over 2 hours and has yet to return a result set so I'm not sure if it's caught in an infinite loop. Any help identifying issues with it would be appreciated!

```
with LEAD_CTE as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, EMAIL, PRIMARY_PHONE, PROGRAMX, TERM_CODE, INQ_TYPE, LEADSOURCE order by CREATEDDATE) as ROWNUMBER
      from LEAD
     where DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y'
       and CREATEDDATE >= (GETDATE() - 7)
),
CTE as
(
    select ROWNUMBER, 'N' as TO_DELETE, CREATEDDATE, 0 as TOTAL_MINUTES, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, EMAIL, PRIMARY_PHONE, PROGRAMX, TERM_CODE, INQ_TYPE, LEADSOURCE
      from LEAD_CTE
     where ROWNUMBER = 1

     union all

    select l.ROWNUMBER,
           case when ((c.TOTAL_MINUTES + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.CREATEDDATE, l.CREATEDDATE)) > 4) then 'N' else 'Y' end as TO_DELETE,
           l.CREATEDDATE,
           case when ((c.TOTAL_MINUTES + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.CREATEDDATE, l.CREATEDDATE)) > 4) then 0 else (c.TOTAL_MINUTES + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.CREATEDDATE, l.CREATEDDATE)) end as TOTAL_MINUTES,
           l.EMAIL, l.FIRSTNAME, l.LASTNAME, l.PRIMARY_PHONE, l.PROGRAMX, l.TERM_CODE, l.INQ_TYPE, l.LEADSOURCE
      from LEAD_CTE l inner join CTE c on l.ROWNUMBER = (c.ROWNUMBER + 1)
)

  select ROWNUMBER, TO_DELETE, CREATEDDATE, TOTAL_MINUTES, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, EMAIL, PRIMARY_PHONE, PROGRAMX, TERM_CODE, INQ_TYPE, LEADSOURCE
    from CTE
order by LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, EMAIL, PRIMARY_PHONE, PROGRAMX, TERM_CODE, INQ_TYPE, LEADSOURCE, CREATEDDATE
```

Sample data:

```
CREATEDDATE             | LASTNAME  | FIRSTNAME | EMAIL         | PRIMARY_PHONE  | PROGRAMX               | TERM_CODE | INQ_TYPE | LEADSOURCE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-09-24 00:06:01.000 | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
2013-09-24 00:18:47.000 | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
2013-09-24 00:18:50.000 | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
2013-09-24 00:18:52.000 | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
2013-09-24 00:18:52.000 | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
2013-09-24 00:18:54.000 | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
2013-09-24 00:18:55.000 | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
2013-09-24 00:18:56.000 | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
2013-09-24 00:18:56.000 | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
```

New CTE with self-join:

```
with LEAD_CTE as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, EMAIL, PRIMARY_PHONE, PROGRAMX, TERM_CODE, INQ_TYPE, LEADSOURCE order by CREATEDDATE) as ROWNUMBER
      from LEAD
     where DELETE_FLAG <> 'Y'
       and CREATEDDATE >= (GETDATE() - 7)
)

  select l1.ROWNUMBER, l1.CREATEDDATE, l2.CREATEDDATE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, l1.CREATEDDATE, l2.CREATEDDATE), l1.LASTNAME, l1.FIRSTNAME, l1.EMAIL, l1.PRIMARY_PHONE, l1.PROGRAMX, l1.TERM_CODE, l1.INQ_TYPE, l1.LEADSOURCE
    from LEAD_CTE l1 left join LEAD_CTE l2
      on l1.ROWNUMBER = (l2.ROWNUMBER + 1)
     and l1.LASTNAME = l2.LASTNAME
     and l1.FIRSTNAME = l2.FIRSTNAME
     and l1.EMAIL = l2.EMAIL
     and l1.PRIMARY_PHONE = l2.PRIMARY_PHONE
     and l1.PROGRAMX = l2.PROGRAMX
     and l1.TERM_CODE = l2.TERM_CODE
     and l1.INQ_TYPE = l2.INQ_TYPE
     and l1.LEADSOURCE = l2.LEADSOURCE
order by l1.ROWNUMBER
```

Actual output:

```
ROWNUMBER | CREATEDDATE             | CREATEDDATE | (no column name) | LASTNAME  | FIRSTNAME | EMAIL         | PRIMARY_PHONE  | PROGRAMX               | TERM_CODE | INQ_TYPE | LEADSOURCE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 2013-09-24 00:06:01.000 | NULL        | NULL             | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
2         | 2013-09-24 00:18:47.000 | NULL        | NULL             | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
3         | 2013-09-24 00:18:50.000 | NULL        | NULL             | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
4         | 2013-09-24 00:18:52.000 | NULL        | NULL             | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
5         | 2013-09-24 00:18:52.000 | NULL        | NULL             | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
6         | 2013-09-24 00:18:54.000 | NULL        | NULL             | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
7         | 2013-09-24 00:18:55.000 | NULL        | NULL             | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
8         | 2013-09-24 00:18:56.000 | NULL        | NULL             | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
9         | 2013-09-24 00:18:56.000 | NULL        | NULL             | Testerson | Testy     | test@test.com | (123) 867-5309 | MS in Higher Education | NULL      | inquiry  | Webform
```

What's interesting is all l2 fields in every record come in as `NULL`, which I found as a result of the `DATEDIFF()` calculations returning `NULL` as well. My expected output would be that all l2 fields would have the values of the next l1 record, with the exception of the last record's l2 fields, which would be `NULL`.

Comment: You're recursive cte looks like the cause. I would do a self join like `from lead_cte t1 left join lead_cte t2 on t1.row_numer = t2.row_numer +1 and t1.lastname = t2.lastnsame and ... the rest of the partitioned fields`

Comment: Your issue is probably a perf one. Try creating temp tables and index on row number you will get better performace. If you have a ton of rows and no index your query is going to be extremely slow.

Comment: @ConradFrix If I use a self-join my groups consist of records that are outside of that 4 minute mark in either direction (either too early or too late).

Comment: @Brian good point so add `and DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.CREATEDDATE, t2.CREATEDDATE) < 4` to the join. If you posted some sample data and expected output people might be more interested in answering this question.

Comment: @ConradFrix Thanks for the recommendation – sample data and actual/expected output has been added.

Comment: You're getting nulls because TERM_CODE is null. When you compare NULL to NULL in a join the join will fail. You could remove it from you join or make it `AND (l1.term_code = l2.term_code 
                       or ( l1.term_code is null and l2.term_code is null))` see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25694/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very close  You just need to add

```
   CASE WHEN Datediff(minute, l2.createddate, l1.createddate ) > 4
                  OR l2.createddate is null
                  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
```

and as I mentioned in the comments you need to deal with the fact that joining on nullable fields is a pain

```
WITH lead_cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY lastname, firstname, email, primary_phone, 
                  programx, 
                  term_code, 
                  inq_type, leadsource 
                    ORDER BY createddate) AS ROWNUMBER 
         FROM   lead 
         WHERE  delete_flag <> 'Y' 
                AND createddate >= ( Getdate() - 7 )) 
SELECT l1.rownumber, 
       l1.createddate, 
       l2.createddate, 
       Datediff(minute, l2.createddate, l1.createddate ) ,
       CASE WHEN Datediff(minute, l2.createddate, l1.createddate ) > 4
                      OR l2.createddate is null
                      THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,

       l1.lastname, 
       l1.firstname, 
       l1.email, 
       l1.primary_phone, 
       l1.programx, 
       l1.term_code, 
       l1.inq_type, 
       l1.leadsource 
FROM   lead_cte l1 
       LEFT JOIN lead_cte l2 
              ON l1.rownumber = l2.rownumber +1
                 AND l1.lastname = l2.lastname 
                 AND l1.firstname = l2.firstname 
                 AND l1.email = l2.email 
                 AND l1.primary_phone = l2.primary_phone 
                 AND l1.programx = l2.programx 
                 AND (l1.term_code = l2.term_code 
                       or ( l1.term_code is null and l2.term_code is null))
                 AND l1.inq_type = l2.inq_type 
                 AND l1.leadsource = l2.leadsource 
ORDER  BY l1.rownumber
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25694/12)

Comment: Agh! Thanks for pointing out the issue with the nulls....definitely a slap-your-forehead moment. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks again!